How should I configurate servers om Process Manager?
I have a server that has 32GB RAM and 16-core CPU and uses SSD storage and 16000 IOPS.
The server OS is Ubunue (20.04) and uses Nginx, PHP-fpm to handle requests.
I need to configure the server so that it can handle very large traffic. Here is the current  config:
# nginx.conf
worker_processes auto;
events { 
    worker_connections 2048
}

# www.conf
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 75
pm.start_servers = 60
pm.min_spare_servers = 55
pm.max_spare_servers = 65

Is that reasonable? And any idea how can I make it better?
It should be noted, both the database, and frontend (nextjs) and backend (laravel) all are on the same server.

You need to profile your app to figure out what it spends time on. Without that information performance tuning is meaningless at best, and destructive at worst.
